# How to PIN MSEdge to taskbar with batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to pin/unpin Microsoft Edge to my taskbar using a batch file. I have several hundred computers to do this to, so I was attempting to make a batch / powershell / vbscript that will unpin all instances of Edge from the taskbar, and then pin one single instance back to the taskbar that way I can be sure it is only pinned once. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from:
http://rolfsnotepad.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/unpin-edge-and-pin-internet-explorer.html

I have tested the pin IE and it works:

```
# The apps array holds hash tables with information about each app that should be pinned. 
# Each hash table has the name of the app, two byte arrays and some strings with various settings 
# for the app's shortcut. The registryEntry byte array contains all the bytes that need to be 
# inserted into the Favorites registry key, while the matchString byte array is used to check 
# if the app is already pinned. # # If you accidentally end up pinning an app that was already pinned, the existing taskbar 
# entry will likely break. For that reason, matchString should be a subset of registryEntry # that you are certain will not change between computers or versions of the app. 
Cls

$apps = @( @{ "appName" = "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
"registryEntry" = @(0,170,1,0,0,58,0,31,128,200,39,52,31,16,92,16,66,170,3,46,228,82,135,214,104,38,0,1,0,37,0,239,190,18,0,0,0,118,241,189,129,21,120,209,1,16,214,92,131,21,120,209,1,16,214,92,131,21,120,209,1,20,0,86,0,49,0,0,0,0,0,182,72,114,151,17,0,84,97,115,107,66,97,114,0,64,0,9,0,4,0,239,190,103,72,105,16,182,72,114,151,46,0,0,0,147,77,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,154,101,231,0,84,0,97,0,115,0,107,0,66,0,97,0,114,0,0,0,22,0,24,1,50,0,43,5,0,0,103,72,103,16,32,0,73,78,84,69,82,78,126,49,46,76,78,75,0,0,170,0,9,0,4,0,239,190,176,72,131,85,182,72,114,151,46,0,0,0,143,221,1,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,90,0,0,0,0,0,156,250,31,0,73,0,110,0,116,0,101,0,114,0,110,0,101,0,116,0,32,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,108,0,111,0,114,0,101,0,114,0,46,0,108,0,110,0,107,0,0,0,64,0,67,0,58,0,92,0,87,0,105,0,110,0,100,0,111,0,119,0,115,0,92,0,83,0,121,0,115,0,116,0,101,0,109,0,51,0,50,0,92,0,105,0,101,0,52,0,117,0,105,0,110,0,105,0,116,0,46,0,101,0,120,0,101,0,44,0,45,0,55,0,51,0,49,0,0,0,28,0,82,0,0,0,29,0,239,190,2,0,77,0,105,0,99,0,114,0,111,0,115,0,111,0,102,0,116,0,46,0,73,0,110,0,116,0,101,0,114,0,110,0,101,0,116,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,108,0,111,0,114,0,101,0,114,0,46,0,68,0,101,0,102,0,97,0,117,0,108,0,116,0,0,0,28,0,0,0)
"matchString" = @(77,0,105,0,99,0,114,0,111,0,115,0,111,0,102,0,116,0,46,0,73,0,110,0,116,0,101,0,114,0,110,0,101,0,116,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,108,0,111,0,114,0,101,0,114,0,46,0,68,0,101,0,102,0,97,0,117,0,108,0,116)
"shortcutPath" = "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Internet Explorer.lnk" 
"shortcutWildcardPath" = "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Internet Explorer*.lnk"
"shortcutTargetPath" = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 
"shortcutWorkingDirectory" = "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" 
} ) 
# Start with the assumption that no apps are pinned. 
$atLeastOneAppWasNotPinned = $false 
foreach ($app in $apps) 
{ 
    $currentAppWasNotPinned = $true 
    # Save the current value of the taskbar registry key as a byte array
    $currentTaskBar = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "hkcu:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband" -Name "Favorites").Favorites # Save the last index for the current taskbar array and the matchString array. 
    $currentTaskBarLastIndex = ($currentTaskBar.Length - 1) 
    $matchStringLastIndex = ($app["matchString"].Length - 1) 
    # Used to keep track of the current location in the byte arrays 
    $matchStringCurrentIndex = 0
    $currentTaskBarCurrentIndex = 0 
    # Loop through the current taskbar array 
    while ($currentTaskBarCurrentIndex -lt $currentTaskBarLastIndex)
    { 
        if ($currentTaskBar[$currentTaskBarCurrentIndex] -eq $app["matchString"][$matchStringCurrentIndex]) 
        { 
            # If the current value of the registry byte array matches the first value of the app byte array, 
            # we save the current registry byte array index.
            $startIndex = $currentTaskBarCurrentIndex 
            # We then proceed to compare the next item in the registry byte array with the next value in the 
            # matchString byte array until we no longer get a match, like a greedy regex. 
            while ($currentTaskBar[$currentTaskBarCurrentIndex] -eq $app["matchString"][$matchStringCurrentIndex]) 
            {
                # If we got a match on the entire matchString, the current app is pinned. 
                if ($matchStringCurrentIndex -eq $matchStringLastIndex) 
                { 
                    $currentAppWasNotPinned = $false 
                } 
                $matchStringCurrentIndex += 1 
                $currentTaskBarCurrentIndex += 1 
            } 
            # Reset the app byte array index counter 
            $matchStringCurrentIndex = 0 
            # Move the registry byte array index back to the location of the match that caused us to enter this # if block.
            $currentTaskBarCurrentIndex = $startIndex 
        } 
        # Step to the next byte in the registry array 
        $currentTaskBarCurrentIndex += 1 
    } 
    if ($currentAppWasNotPinned -or ($currentTaskBarLastIndex -eq 0)) 
    { 
        $atLeastOneAppWasNotPinned = $true 
        # For various reasons you could end up having a shortcut in the taskbar directory even if the app # the shortcut points to isn't pinned. 
        #To make sure that any such shortcuts won't cause us any # issues, remove them. 
        Remove-Item ((Get-ChildItem Env:APPDATA).Value + $app["shortcutWildcardPath"]) # Create the app's shortcut in the taskbar directory. 
        $taskbarShortcutPath = (Get-ChildItem Env:APPDATA).Value + $app["shortcutPath"]
        $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
        $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($taskbarShortcutPath) 
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $app["shortcutTargetPath"]
        $Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $app["shortcutWildcardPath"]
        $Shortcut.Save() 
        # Add the app's byte array to the current taskbar registry entry. 
        $taskBar = $app["registryEntry"] + $currentTaskBar
         # Overwrite the existing taskbar registry key with the version that has the current app pinned. 
        New-ItemProperty -Path "hkcu:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband" -Name "Favorites" -Value $taskBar -PropertyType Binary -Force | Out-Null
    } 
} 
if ($atLeastOneAppWasNotPinned) 
{ 
    Write-Output "At least one app was not pinned, pinning and restarting explorer.exe to refresh taskbar."
    # Restart Explorer to refresh the taskbar 
    Invoke-Expression "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe" 
    Invoke-Expression "start explorer.exe" 
} 
else 
{
    Write-Output "All apps are pinned." 
}
```

Comment: I asked to PIN Edge, NOT Internet Explorer.

Comment: My builds are LTSB so I cannot test Edge but the source link has code for pining Edge.

Comment: No, it has unpinning edge.